# New user of Azure: Access to Query Editor

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I am new user of Azure. After few initial steps of opening an account with Azure portal and then after creating a database, now I cannot enter the page Query Editor. In particular, I cannot go thru this registration page. What did I do wrong here?

[image: My screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to login using Active Directory Authentication. However, I suspect you may not have configured an **Azure AD Admin** for your server.

You can login to your DB either after [provisioning an Azure AD admin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-configure?tabs=azure-powershell#provision-azure-ad-admin-sql-database), or using the [SQL Server admin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/connect-query-portal#connect-using-sql-authentication) credentials that you set up while creating the server.